# Uncaught Error: Assertion Failed: You may not set `id` as an attribute on your model --- want to duplicate id attribute

Tags: ember.js, set, duplicates

I have a model called group having multiple attributes, I also want to save my id information to some other attribute because of some reasons to pass the model info to somewhere else.

---

```
import DS from 'ember-data';

var group = DS.Model.extend({

    groupId : DS.attr('string'),//want to duplicate id here
    groupName: DS.attr('string'),
    groupRegion: DS.attr('string'),
    groupCountry: DS.attr('string'),
    groupSegment: DS.attr('string'),
    groupSubSegment: DS.attr('string'),
    isSelected: DS.attr('boolean'),
    isExpand: DS.attr('boolean')
});

export default group;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can make use of the ready hook.

```
var group = DS.Model.extend({

 groupId : DS.attr(),//want to duplicate id here
 groupName: DS.attr('string'),
 groupRegion: DS.attr('string'),
 groupCountry: DS.attr('string'),
 groupSegment: DS.attr('string'),
 groupSubSegment: DS.attr('string'),
 isSelected: DS.attr('boolean'),
 isExpand: DS.attr('boolean'),
 ready(){
  this.set('groupId',this.get('id'));
 }
```

});